# Derivative-free apporach to find a zero of a mapping from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  is a continuous function with a sign change on an interval $[a,b]$.
There is a classic derivative-free algorithm to find a zero with very desirable
properties:

1. super-linear convergence
2. all evaluations of  $f$  stay within $[a,b]$
3. code available (e.g., on netlib)
   The method uses a clever combination of bisection search and polynomial models
   of the function as it get closer and closer to a zero.

I want to extend the idea to a mapping  $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$;
Suppose I have a triangle (simplex) in $\mathbb R^2$ with  $f$  evaluated at the three
vertices $(a,b,c)$. In other words, each vertex is "labeled" with a point in $\mathbb R^2$.
There is a criterion based on the signs of the vertex labels that determines
if there is a zero of  $f$  interior to the simplex.
I am looking for an algorithm/code to find such a zero

1. must only evaluate  $f$  at points interior to (or on) the simplex
2. ideally super-linear convergence
3. probably OK to assume that the zero is unique

It is not hard to imagine an extension of bisection: find the mid-points of each side to define a new inscribed simplex. Now, the original simplex has been sub-divided into four
simplicies (non-overlapping). Evaluate the function of each of the three new vertices and
apply the sign criterion to isolate the zero to one of the four sub-divisions.
Then, recurse. But, it is hard to imagine that such a simple scheme would be
super-linearly convergent.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: and, still derivative-free!

Comment: Are you saying that there already exists a criterion to determine if there is a zero in the interior of the triangle, or is that what you're looking for? Because I don't believe such a criterion can exist without information along the boundary or further restrictions on $f$.

Comment: I think you CAN make this deduction, similar to the conclusion that if there is a sign change on an interval, then a continuous function should have a zero interior to the interval. The technique is used for simplicial continuation solvers.

Comment: See, e.g., the standard text on Numerical Continuation by Allgower and Georg. It involves a "labeling matrix" and its inverse having a certain pattern of signs called lexicographically positive.

Comment: I am in the process of implementing the obvious divide and conquer algorithm and will report. But, do not expect it to be very efficient in terms of the number of function evaluations required ...

Comment: Okay, from what I gather there are some implicit assumptions that $f$ is sufficiently smooth, and the triangle is sufficiently small, so that $f$ can be reasonably well approximated by a linear function on the triangle. (See the subsection on "truncation errors" in the Allgower and Georg text.)